# Which followers will have their level changed when we use the setlevel command?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

[How do I change follower level cap with console commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61120/how-do-i-change-follower-level-cap-with-console-commands) says we can use `setlevel` to change attribuutes on the NPC.

But which NPC? The one we click? The one that follow us (can be several with mods) The one we are currently talking to? Or do we set the id somewhere via console?

Comment: The one you click.

Answer (score 2):

You will change the entity (NPC or static object) that you have selected by clicking them whilst the console is open.

Also note that clicking an entity may be a hard task, you may sometimes get another object. If you aren't seeing a change occur after you do a `getav` etc, then it's likely that you have clicked the wrong entity. Try clicking them at a different angle.